# remove same values from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => u1,u2
    [1] => u2,u1
    [2] => u4,u3
    [3] => u1,u3
    [4] => u1,u2
)
```

I want to remove similar values from the array
I want an out put like

```
Array
    (
        [0] => u1,u2
        [1] => u4,u3
        [2] => u1,u3

    )
```

I tried to loop thru the input array, sort the value of the indexes alphabetically and then tried array_search to find the repeated values. but never really got the desired output

any help apprecated

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @RoyalBg: since array_unique was not working i tried all these steps.It will not work

Comment: As I have said in the comments to the answers, none of them will work since `u1,u2 !== u2,u1`. `array_unique` matches exact values only.

Comment: Tried exploding the pairs in another arrays and compare the unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `array_unique()` alone, since this will only match exact duplicates only. As a result, you'll have to loop over and check each permutation of that value.

You can use `array_unique()` to begin with, and then loop over:

```
$myArray = array('u1,u2', 'u2,u1', 'u4,u3', 'u1,u3', 'u1,u2');

$newArr = array_unique($myArray);
$holderArr = array();

foreach($newArr as $val)
{
    $parts = explode(',', $val);
    $part1 = $parts[0].','.$parts[1];
    $part2 = $parts[1].','.$parts[0];

    if(!in_array($part1, $holderArr) && !in_array($part2, $holderArr))
    {
        $holderArr[] = $val;
    }
}

$newArr = $holderArr;
```

The above code will produce the following output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => u1,u2 
    [1] => u4,u3 
    [2] => u1,u3 
)
```

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks a lot Ben :). Thanks to all who tried to solve this.

Comment: Thought it was the decision :) +1 for the whole answer.

Comment: Glad to help. A note to the others, it sometimes helps to read the whole question :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_unique()` PHP function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: I don't think `array_unique` will work here, since `u1,u2 !== u2,u1`.

Comment: " want to remove similar values"

u1,u2 !== u2,u1 -> they are not similar i think.

Comment: See the desired output. `unique` != `similar`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `array_unique($array)`

Answer (score 0):

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: I don't think `array_unique` will work here, since `u1,u2 !== u2,u1`.

Answer (score 0):

since u1,u2 !== u2,u1

```
    $array=array('u1,u2','u2,u1','u4,u3','u1,u3','u1,u2');
    foreach($array as $k=>$v)
    {
        $sub_arr = explode(',',$v);
        asort($sub_arr);
        $array[$k] = implode(',',$sub_arr);
    }

    $unique_array = array_unique($array);

    //$unique_array = array_values($unique_array) //if you want to preserve the ordered keys
```