# JAVA : remove duplicates from Array with pattern

Tags: java

I am new to Java, With respect to this question [remove same values from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463084/remove-same-values-from-an-array) 
How can we achieve it using java. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Arrays are a bad choice for that. Use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Actually a HashSet would be the way to go for a list of Strings. Though nallar is right. This has been answered before.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Set (e.g. HashSet), or a Map (e.g. HashMap).
For each value in the array, just place it in the Set (or as a key in the Map).

You will then have a collection without duplicates (you can transform it back to an array if you need).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should use `HashSet`, it will remove duplicate values.

For sorting, you should use `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply by using the collections.

use set or HashMap and put the elements in the collections. when you retrieve you will get the unique elements .

If you are looking for pattern matching... better for the RegEx.